# login using ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: c#, asp.net

NET Entity Data Model to get data form Users table which has a foreign key usertypeid  from  table Usertypes

the code works fine i just want the code to get data form tow tables which the tow tables have  a foreign key called usertypeid

ex table1(foreign key usertypeid)  table2((foreign key usertypeid))

```
    var result = _datamoel.Users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.UserName.Equals(txtuser.Text) && i.Password.Equals(txtpass.Text));

    if (result != null )
    {

        result.UserTypeReference.Load();
        Session["Username"] = txtuser.Text;

       if (result.UserType.TypeName.Equals("Admin"))
            Response.Redirect("Admin/AdminHomePage.aspx");
        else if (result.UserType.TypeName.Equals("Clerk"))
            Response.Redirect("Clerk/ClerkPage.aspx");
      }

    else

        lblmsgw.Text = "UserName/Passsword Not Correct! Please Change UserName/Passsword and Try again";
```

Comment: Use Include and specify the navigation prpoerty you want to fetch from database eg. _datamodel.Users.Include("table2").FirstOrDefault....

Comment: _datamodel.Users.Include("table2").FirstOrDefault ok how can fetch data from table2

Comment: The include will fetch the data for you and fill out your navigation property, just have a look at the collection of your table2 from your result object. Eg. Result.Table2s the collection should have values inside.